# Is it possible to use HTML5 to display an MPEG Transport Stream video?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mpeg2-ts

I have several MPEG2 Transport Stream videos with KLV metadata embedded in them. I would like to display the videos in a web browser. Is it possible to use the HTML5 `<video>` tag to play a video of this type in a web browser?

If I use a converter to pull the video out of the MPEG-TS container and create an MPEG4 file encoded with H.264, then I can get the video to show up in a browser. But is there any possible way I could display these videos without having to convert them into a different format? I need to keep the KLV data around so I can do other stuff with it.

Comment: What specific video codecs are supported are browser dependent. I don't believe there is currently any browser support for MPEG2.

Comment: Did you ever come across a solution to this? Is it possible to retrieve KLV metadata once the video reaches the browser?

Answer (score 1):

The actual video codec support is still up to the browser, but some support MPEG2-TS natively as a transport, and if they don't you can do software demuxing using [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js).  Reading KLV is [an unresolved issue](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/1406) but you "should" (per that issue) be able to access the raw binary stream and parse out the values yourself -- not *trivial*, as such, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no browser that support mpeg2. 
You can use service like: vid.ly and have all the formats you need.